# Why does the POSIX regular expression "^a*$" match strings containing a dollar sign?

Tags: regex, unix, posix

I would expect that the regular expression `^[a-z]*$` would not match `random$something`

However, this matches when I try it on the shell:

```
~# echo "random$something" | grep "^[a-z]*$"
random

~# echo "aaaaa$something" | grep "^a*$"
aaaaa
```

Why is this happening?

I've seen this on both Solaris and RedHat Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you just do

```
echo "aaaaa$something"
```

without the grep, the result is

```
aaaaa
```

This is because the shell is trying to interpret $something as a variable.
If you change the double quotes to single quotes, you'll see the expected behavior; that is no result.